# Calling methods or properties of objects in List

Tags: c#, list, xna

I'm programming a debug window in my XNA game. It's just a `StringBuilder` that prints stuff out. However I want to make it more interactive. For example a `Player` class:

```
public class Player
{
   public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
   public int Health { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a list of properties (or methods maybe) to call. So something like:

```
list.Add(player1.Position);
list.Add(player1.Health);
list.Add(enemy2.Position);
```

So then with each update, the list would call these properties and print their values. Is there any way to do this? Do I need to use reflection? Would it be much different using methods instead of properties?

EDIT: This is what I currently have https://github.com/nanexcool/xna-debug-window/blob/master/DebugWindow.cs

It works by specifying an object and a property name as a string, but there's probably a nicer way to do it.

Comment: Can you provide exactly how you want your debug window to work? Something like the Watch window in Visual Studio perhaps?

Comment: Yes, you can use reflection to get all of the property names and their values for a current item.  Just doing some reading up on it.

Comment: It's a window that I draw on screen. Basically just iterate over objects, calling certain properties, and displaying their .ToString()

Comment: This is what I have so far, a Dictionary<object, string>. I add a player .Add(player1, "Position").  Then I get the data by iterating over the dictionary doing: string data = s.Key.GetType().GetProperty(s.Value).GetValue(s.Key, null).ToString();  Seems to be working, there's probably an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of tuples (or dictionary) with the property name and a delegate that returns that property:

```
using DebugTuple = Tuple<string, Func<string>>;

class Program
{  
    class Player
    {
        public int x;
        public Player(int y) { x = y; }            
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        Player one = new Player(25);
        Player two = new Player(50);

        List<DebugTuple> calls = new List<DebugTuple>();
        calls.Add(new DebugTuple("Player 1 health", delegate() { return one.x.ToString(); })); 
        calls.Add(new DebugTuple("Player 2 health", delegate() { return two.x.ToString(); })); 

        foreach (DebugTuple c in calls)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Item1 + ": " + c.Item2());

        //Change values and make sure it outputs new values
        one.x = 100;
        two.x = 0;

        foreach (DebugTuple c in calls)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Item1 + ": " + c.Item2());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

output:

```
Player 1 health: 25
Player 2 health: 50
Player 1 health: 100
Player 2 health: 0
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. Thank you! I'm changing the tuple to Tuple<string, Func<object>> so I can just do return one.x and then do the ToString on c.Item2().ToString(). Gonna try that.

Comment: No problem. Just a word of warning: when you create a delegate that references an object, the garbage collector will no longer delete that object when it falls out of scope (since it is still in the scope of the delegate). If you will be creating lots of objects (or very big objects) and memory usage is an issue, you should come up with some way of ensuring that when an object is deleted, you also delete all of the delegates that reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this useful as well:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents your player class.
/// </summary>
class Player
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the health of the player.
    /// </summary>
    [DebugExtensions.DebugMePlease()]
    public int Health { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the player.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a string representation of the player object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The player object as string representation.</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contains some extensions useful for debugging.
/// </summary>
public static class DebugExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents our custom attribute called "DebugMePlease".
    /// Properties marked with this attribute will be printed automatically.
    /// </summary>
    public class DebugMePlease : Attribute
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Continas all objects that shall be monitored.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<object> DebugList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="DebugExtensions"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static DebugExtensions()
    {
        DebugList = new List<object>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints the values of all objects in the debugList.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Print()
    {
        foreach (object o in DebugList)
        {
            var members = from member in o.GetType().GetProperties()
                          from attribute in member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebugMePlease), true)
                          select member;

            foreach (var z in members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}: {2}", o.ToString(), z.Name, z.GetValue(o)));
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Contains the entry point of our application.
/// </summary>
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The entry point of our application. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Possibly specified command line arguments.</param>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player t = new Player();
        t.Name = "Chuck Norris";
        t.Health = int.MaxValue; // Becaus it's Chuck Norris ;-)

        // Add the object to the debug list.
        DebugExtensions.DebugList.Add(t);

        // Print all properties marked with the "DebugMePlease" attribute.
        DebugExtensions.Print();

        // Change something.
        t.Health = 0;

        // Print again and hopefully be happy.
        DebugExtensions.Print();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missunderstand something but if you have already a list which contains the references can't you just print them by using .ToString()?
(Of course you'd have to override ToString() in your own classes.)

Comment: Problem is if I add player1.Position or enemy.Health directly to a list what's added is the value and won't be updated.

Comment: That's because you store value types. If you would store only reference types there would be no problem of course.

Comment: I know! But I *want* to store value types such as Vector2, and then invoke the property to see if it's changed.

Comment: You could implement a property changed event in your data structures and fire the event every time the properties change (or use INotifyPropertyChanged). From the outside you would then just have to connect to the event and always receive the current value.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged sounds good, but that would mean modifying every class that I want to get info from.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Currently I do not have a better idea. I'm pretty sure you could use reflection as well but I guess modifying the classes should be easier (depending on the number of them of course).

Comment: Mind looking at my code? I updated my question with a link to GitHub.